# is it possibile to use unity project as an android studio activity?

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, mobile-development

I am trying to create an android application, of which its components are build partly on android studio and partly on unity. i can't do everything with android studio or everything with unity, so i would like a way to merge the two parts. my plan is to integrate the part built in unity as the main activity on androids studio and then create the other activities(screens) of my app on android studio and create a way to slide scroll between those screens(activities). i would like this configuration to work as a single 'precess'.

is this posible to do ?

I am still a beginner, so if I didn't explain well please tell me.

I tried to search for information that would be useful to me but on found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You have to make an Android Export and add it to your main project. then call unity's activity which is registered on AndroidManifest and Unity part will be run.